# Change button's position after cloning div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two functions, what they do is that they duplicate a div on button's click, it's working fine but i want when i clone the div, the button that i clicked to change position below the cloned div because it stays in it's place, how can i do that? here is my code:

```js
document.getElementById('CloneBtn').onclick = duplicate;
var i = 0;
var original = document.getElementById('duplicater');
function duplicate() {
    var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
    clone.id = "duplicetor" + ++i;
    original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
}
```

```html
<div id="duplicater">
    <p>Clone me</p>
</div>
<button type="button" id="CloneBtn" onlick="duplicate()">Clone Div</button>
```

Comment: Just play with css without any adding html tag exmaple div{float:left; display:table;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap your `#duplicater` element in another container and keep the button separate. The new element will become the `parentNode` for the new clones and keep them all organized.

```js
document.getElementById('CloneBtn').onclick = duplicate;

var i = 0;
var original = document.getElementById('duplicater');

function duplicate() {
  var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
  clone.id = "duplicetor" + ++i;
  original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="duplicater">
    <p>Clone me</p>
  </div>
</div>

<button type="button" id="CloneBtn" onlick="duplicate()">Clone 1</button>
```

---

Update: Added a heading per your comments below.

```js
document.getElementById('CloneBtn').onclick = duplicate;

var i = 1;
var original = document.getElementById('duplicater');

function duplicate() {
  var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
  clone.id = "duplicetor" + ++i;
  original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
  clone.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<h3>Cloned</h3>');  
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="duplicater">
    <p>Clone me</p>
  </div>
</div>

<button type="button" id="CloneBtn" onlick="duplicate()">Clone 1</button>
```

Comment: thank you! but can you help me in another thing please, i want to add a heading before each cloned div, can you do that for me?

Comment: @jessica Can you be more specific about what you need? Why not just put `<h1>Heading</h1>` above the `<p>Clone me </p>`?

Comment: I want a different heading on the cloned div not the same as the main heading

Comment: @jessica Updated my answer - see the bottom. Does that help?